# librosa producing "undetailed" MFCC spectrogram

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, spectrogram, librosa, mfcc

I am trying to create an MFCC plot with librosa but the plot just doesn't appear to be very detailed. The goal is to present this MFCC spectrogram to a neural network. The audio file I am testing with is around 1 second long and is from the Google Speech Commands dataset. My code is:

```py
WINDOW_SIZE = 20
NFFT=int((WINDOW_SIZE/1000)*16000)

samples, _ = librosa.load(f, sr=16000) 

mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=samples[:16000], sr=16000, n_fft=NFFT, n_mfcc=40)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
librosa.display.specshow(mfccs, x_axis='time')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('MFCC')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the MFCC spectrogram being produced:

[image: mfcc spec]

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354627/942774 helps: specify sampling rate and hop size when using `specshow`, otherwise the *wrong* values are assumed.

Answer (score 2):

The 0th coefficient has a lot more energy compared to the rest, so differences in the other bands don't show very well in the plot.

You may want to normalize this such that all coefficients are on the same scale. You can compute the mean and std per coefficient and then standardize by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. This can be done per clip, or across the training set.