# Why does librosa STFT show wrong frequencies?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, signal-processing, librosa, spectrogram

I generated a 200 Hz sine wave using numpy and then used librosas `stft()` and `specshow()` functions to show a spectrogram. However, the frequency it is showing is not 200 Hz. When I use matplotlibs `magnitude_spectrum()` function, it shows exactly 200 Hz. Does anyone know why that might be? Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be much appriciated.

The results from librosas spectrogram and matplotlibs frequency spectrum can be seen in the image below.

Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import librosa
import librosa.display

sr = 20000
freq1 = 200
n_fft=2000

x = np.linspace(0, 1, sr)
y = 0.5*np.sin(freq1 * 2 * np.pi * x)
no_window = np.linspace(1, 1, n_fft)
D = np.abs(librosa.stft(y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=int(n_fft/2), window=no_window, center=False,))

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4))

librosa.display.specshow(D, y_axis='linear')

plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylim(0, 250)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4))

plt.magnitude_spectrum(y, Fs=sr, color='C1', window=mlab.window_none)
plt.xlim(0, 250)
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [-]')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Librosas spectrogram vs Matplotlibs frequency spectrum]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just passing the results to `specshow` is not enough. You also need to tell it what scale these results are on. You do this be passing the sample rate parameter `sr` like this:

```
librosa.display.specshow(D, y_axis='linear', sr=sr)
```

If you don't, it [defaults](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html) to `sr=22050, hop_length=512`, which is certainly not correct in your case.

This is similar to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354627/942774).

Comment: Oh, even after so much time I managed to miss these parameters. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome. Frankly, it's an easy oversight, as it's not entirely intuitive that `D` does not describe the whole thing including metadata as it (perhaps) would be in an object-oriented world.

Comment: I'd like to get my hands on that metadata (if that means the frequency data). Something like numpy's `fft.fftfreq()`, which is quite cumbersome and intuitive to use.